# How can I create a thread lock/synchronization for meaningfully equal objects and prevent parallel execution of the respective threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, locks

```
private Map<CustomerKey, Customer> customerMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<CustomerKey, Customer>();

public Customer getCustomer(CustomerKey customerKey)
{   
    Customer customer = customerMap.get(customerKey);
    if(null == customer)
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            customer = customerMap.get(customerKey); // Added line
            if(null == customer)
            {
                customer = new Customer();
                customerMap.put(customerKey, customer); // Added line
            }
        }
    }
    return customer;
}
```

This is how we usually do object level locking.

In this example, object level locking is applied irrespective of the value of the customerKey object. So even for different customerKey objects, the particular block will be synchronized. I don't want this behavior.

Instead of "this" variable, if I acquire lock on customerKey object like below,

**synchronized(customerKey)**

Multiple  threads can be passing different customerKey objects but with same value which means they are meaningfully equal (customerKeyThread1.equals(customerKeyThread2)) but not same objects (customerKeyThread1 != customerKeyThread2)

So locking at customerKey object is also not a valid solution.

So I need some logic which provides synchronization for a set of code not only for same object but also for **meaningfully equal objects**. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: aren't you looking for `ConcurrentHashMap::getOrDefault` here?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response. But I don't think this method will be useful in my case. Could you please elaborate a little more about your solution?

Comment: it seems that your `getCustomer` needs to do one thing in a thread-safe way: get the customer if it is in the `Map` *or* get a new `Customer`. this is what `getOrDefault` is for. if that is not the case, make your question more clear for us

Comment: Sorry, Just edited the original post. Added couple of lines

For example, if 2 threads are entering into this method in parallel with two meaningfully equal key, 

1) If I dont put synchronization, two Customer objects will be created unnecessarily.
2) If I put synchronization by locking "this" object, even for threads with different CustomerKey objects will fall into synchronziation

Comment: So I need some mechanism to create one Customer object even if multiple threads coming in parallel with meaningfully equal keys and not do any synchronization for threads with meaningfully unequal keys

Comment: Based on your description, It seems like Eugene is offering the correct solution.

Comment: working on an answer....

Comment: You could overwrite the user if it already exists in the map considering you are just creating a new instance. Maybe the overhead of overwriting the customer once in a while is low compared to the one introduced by the lock.

Comment: @TomDrake see my answer

Comment: Sorry to ask, but did my answer helped u somehow

Answer (score 0):

Well you made it simpler in such a case (it seems to me), just use `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` as it is documented with:

> the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null.

It also says that:

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically....

So you could do:

```
public Customer getCustomer(CustomerKey customerKey) {
    return customerMap.computeIfAbsent(customerKey, x-> new Customer());
}
```